# Show all data from ManyToMany Fields

Tags: django

I'm try to get all data from relationship manytomany, this is my model

```
class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='products/', null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    stock = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Categories)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Categories(models.Model):
   name =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

for get the data from products try this:

```
class Products(ListView):

    model = Product
    template_name = "products.html"
```

on the template return similar to this:

```
_______________________________
# | name  | price | Categories |
________________________________
1 | Pepsi | 1.25  |            |
2 | Choco.| 2.50  |            |
```

for generate this table i use a cycle for:

```
{% for product in object_list %}
<tr>
<td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
<td>{{ product.name }}</td>
<td>{{ product.price }}</td>
<td>{{ product.categories }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

in this case return empty the categories selected on the product..please any suggest.. thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the `categories` attribute of `Product` is a many to many relation thus it resolves to another query with multiple objects. It is another queryset just line your `object_list`, thus you need to explicitly tell the template how to print that.

Here's a sample solution:

```
{% for product in object_list %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.price }}</td>
    <td>
        {% for category in product.categories.all %}
            {{ category }}
        {% endfor %}
    </td>
{% endfor %}
```

Or you could use the django join template tag (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#join):

```
{% for product in object_list %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.price }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.categories.all|join:", " }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Some more quick comments to help you since you are starting Django:

- `class Categories` is not a very good name for your model. I propose naming it `class Category` since each `Category` instance will correlate to a single category.
- `class Products` is a bad name for a view. I propose naming it `class ProductListView` so you'll know that it is a ListView of your products. Also keep a similar naming scheme to all your views.
- Using a `FloatField` to save prices (monetary values) is always problematic. You'll have strange values when you try to do aggregates on that column (i.e adding or taking averages). This is because of how float numbers work (i.e some values cannot be represented exactly by a float but you'll get a very close approximation instead like instead of 1.3 you'll have 1.2999999999999 with the float). Use a `DecimalField` instead to properly save monetary values.
- You can pass a `context_object_name` attribute to your `ListView` so that you could use it instead of `object_list`. Thus, if you'd defined your `ProductListView` like this:

```
    class ProductListView(ListView):
        model = Product
        template_name = "products.html"        
        context_object_name = 'products'
```

you'd be able to do `{% for product in products %} ...` in your template.

- There's no reason to explicitly define the `template_name` attribute of your ListView since django generates one from the class and package name. Take a look at this portion of the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#generic-views-of-objects and especially this paragraph:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#generic-views-of-objects

> We could explicitly tell the view which template to use by adding a template_name attribute to the view, but in the absence of an explicit template Django will infer one from the object’s name. In this case, the inferred template will be "books/publisher_list.html" – the “books” part comes from the name of the app that defines the model, while the “publisher” bit is just the lowercased version of the model’s name.

Use `template_name` only if you intent to add a 2nd list view for a class to make it explicit that this is intentional.

Comment: thanks ..you solve my problem..I was looking for this for 2 days this answer..thanks

Comment: You're welcome, take a look at my other general comments about Django if you want !